# Salesforce Apex class to sort years and year ranges giving incorrect output

Tags: salesforce, apex, salesforce-lightning

Tried writing a sort method where input was given like a string of comma-delimited years and year ranges `String input = '2017, 2018,2020-2023,1800-1700,2020,20a9,19z5-1990,2025,20261,2013';`

Expectation is to get a string of comma-delimited years and year ranges,and remove all duplicates and invalid inputs.

Below is  class written which  is not giving me correct output

```
            public class sortYearAndYearRangesString {
              public static List<String> sortSpecialString(String input) {
                   system.debug(input);
                    List<String> inputList = input.split('');
                  system.debug(inputList);
                Map<Integer,String> stringMap = new Map<Integer,String>();
                  system.debug(stringMap);
                List<String> output = new List<String>();
                for (Integer i=0; i<inputList.size(); i++) {
                    String charac = inputList[i];
                    if(!charac.isAlphaNumeric()) {
                         system.debug(charac);
                        stringMap.put(i,charac);
                    }else {
                        output.add(charac);
                        system.debug(output);
                    }
                }
                String finalString =  String.join(output,'');
                  system.debug(finalString);
                List<String> resultList = finalString.reverse().split('');
                for( Integer I : stringMap.keySet() ){
                    system.debug(I);
                    resultList.add(I,stringMap.get(I));
                     system.debug(resultList);
                    
                   
                }
                  return resultList;      
                   }
```

Tried validating the solution in Anonymous Apex but no success

```
             public static void validateSolution() {
             String input = '2017, 2018,2020-2023,1800-1700,2020,20a9,19z5-1990,2025,20261,2013';
             List<Integer> expected = new List<Integer> {2013,2017,2018,2020,2021,2022,2023,2025};
             List<Integer> actual = sortYearAndYearRangesString(input);
             
             System.assertEquals(expected, actual, 'Invalid Results');
             }
            }
```

Your help is appreciated

Regards

Carolyn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your test case, you should also define at least a constant for a maximum value, in order to exclude `20261`. Probably you need a minimum too.
I used 1700 as min and 4000 as max because these are the limits for a Date or Datatime field: [docs](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000318735&type=1)
Moreover the method must return a `List<Integer>` instead of a `List<String>`.
You don't need a Map, just a Set would work.

```java
public class SortYearAndYearRangesString {
    private static final Integer MAX_YEAR = 4000;
    private static final Integer MIN_YEAR = 1700;

    public static List<Integer> sortSpecialString(String input) {
        Set<Integer> output = new Set<Integer>();
        List<String> yearsList = input.split(',');
        for (String yearString : yearsList) {
            yearString = yearString.trim();
            if (yearString.isNumeric()) {
                try {
                    Integer year = Integer.valueOf(yearString);
                    if (year >= MIN_YEAR && year <= MAX_YEAR) {
                        output.add(year);
                    }
                } catch (TypeException e) {
                    System.debug(e.getMessage());
                }
            } else {
                List<String> range = yearString.split('-');
                if (range.size() == 2 && range[0].isNumeric() && range[1].isNumeric()) {
                    try {
                        // Modify the following two lines once you know how to handle range like 1300-1500 or 3950-4150
                        Integer firstYear = Math.max(Integer.valueOf(range[0]), MIN_YEAR);
                        Integer lastYear = Math.min(Integer.valueOf(range[1]), MAX_YEAR);
                        while (firstYear <= lastYear) {
                            output.add(firstYear++);
                        }
                    } catch (TypeException e) {
                        System.debug(e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        List<Integer> sortedYears = new List<Integer>(output);
        sortedYears.sort();
        return sortedYears;
    }
}
```

If a range that exceed the boundaries (like `1300-1500` or `3950-4150`) should be treated as invalid and skipped, please change these lines

```
Integer firstYear = Math.max(Integer.valueOf(range[0]), MIN_YEAR);
Integer lastYear = Math.min(Integer.valueOf(range[1]), MAX_YEAR);
while (firstYear <= lastYear) {
    output.add(firstYear++);
}
```

as follow:

```
Integer firstYear = Integer.valueOf(range[0]);
Integer lastYear = Integer.valueOf(range[1]);
if (firstYear >= MIN_YEAR && lastYear <= MAX_YEAR) {
    while (firstYear <= lastYear) {
        output.add(firstYear++);
    }
}
```

---

I tested it in anonymous console with the following code:

```java
String input = '2017, 2018,2020-2023,1800-1700,2020,20a9,19z5-1990,2025,20261,2013';
List<Integer> expected = new List<Integer> {2013,2017,2018,2020,2021,2022,2023,2025};
List<Integer> actual = SortYearAndYearRangesString.sortSpecialString(input);
System.debug(actual);
System.assertEquals(expected, actual, 'Invalid Results');

input = '1500,2017, 2018,2020-2023,1800-1700,2020,20a9,19z5-1990,2025,20261,2013,3998-4002';
expected = new List<Integer> {2013,2017,2018,2020,2021,2022,2023,2025,3998,3999,4000};
actual = SortYearAndYearRangesString.sortSpecialString(input);
System.assertEquals(expected, actual, 'Invalid Results');
```

Answer (score 1):

I made some changes to the class.

It does increment all ranges - and doesn't check if they're years that would make sense. You'll need to add that logic in there (e.g. 1500-1600 would return all years between 1500-1600. Prob best to cap at 1900 or something)

```
public class SortYearAndYearRangesString{
public static List<Integer> sortSpecialString(String input){
    List<String> inputList = input.split(',');
    Set<Integer> output = new Set<Integer>();
    system.debug('input ' + input);
    system.debug('inputList ' + inputList);
    for (String s : inputList){
        Set<Integer> tempSet = new Set<Integer>();
        s.remove(' ');
        if (s.contains('-')){
            //// break the ranges and fill in years
            List<String> tempSet2 = s.split('-');
            for (String s2 : tempSet2){
                try{
                    ///capture valid integers
                    Integer tempInt = Integer.valueOf(s2);
                    tempSet.add(tempInt);
                } catch (Exception e){
                    tempSet.clear();
                    break;
                }
            }
            System.debug('set ' + tempSet);
            if (tempSet.size() > 1){
                List<Integer> tempList = new List<Integer>(tempSet);
                tempList.sort ();
                Integer r = tempList.size() - 1;
                // iterate through the years
                for (Integer i = tempList.get(0); i < tempList.get(r); i++){
                    tempSet.add(i) ;
                }
            }
        } else{
            try{
                ///capture valid integers
                Integer tempInt = Integer.valueOf(s);
                tempSet.add(tempInt);
            } catch (Exception e){
                continue;
            }
        }
        output.addAll(tempSet);
    }

    // output is currently set of ints, need to convert to list of integer

    List<Integer> finalOutput = new List<Integer>(output);
    finalOutput.sort ();
    System.debug('finalOutput :' + finalOutput);
    return finalOutput;
}}
```

Comment: havent got the output by running the ```public static void validateSolution() {
             String input = '2017, 2018,2020-2023,1800-1700,2020,20a9,19z5-1990,2025,20261,2013';
             List<Integer> expected = new List<Integer> {2013,2017,2018,2020,2021,2022,2023,2025};
             List<Integer> actual = SortYearAndYearRangesString.sortSpecialString(input);
             
             System.assertEquals(expected, actual, 'Invalid Results');
             }```